# How can I override phtml and xml files overrided by custom theme Magento2.3

Tags: magento2.3, template-override

How can I override phtml, XML and CSS files that are overridden or created in custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via creating a new child theme.

like below:

suppose this is your current theme:

> app\design\frontend\your_namespace\your_customtheme

Copy your current theme in same directory like below:

Now you have to update your code in theme.xml

It should like:

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Custom child theme</title>
    <parent>your_parent_namespace/your_parent_theme</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

Make sure you have to give your current theme name as a parent in newly created child theme.

Comment: I already have a custom paid theme, But I want to override theme templates, so if I am going to update it will not affect my changes

Comment: override theme template using custom module ??

Comment: Like you have already one theme like app\design\frontend\your_namespace\your_customtheme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml and you want to override your custom theme template ?

Comment: @RaviSoni, Yes I already have theme and want to override template of theme and some of things that is override by theme.

Comment: For that you have to create one child theme. And you can assign your current theme as a parent. That's only way.

Comment: @RaviSoni, Thanks, Any referance link ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check